# how to change the icon and package name of a default application on the launcher dock named launcher3 to another icon and package name

Tags: android, android-launcher

how to change the icon and package name of a default application on the launcher dock named launcher3 to another icon and package name of another application .  the important thing is i want to replace the default app on launcher3's dock with my one called mark.lua.gp

i tried changing the default package name in the dock of launcher3.apk app but it only shows the icon on the home screen but not the icon in the dock.  and the default application's position in the dock is now empty.

Anyone with knowledge on this please help, any guidance I greatly appreciate and appreciate